# Prevent another app from reading password saved by Keytar

Tags: node.js, electron, atom-editor, keytar

In `keytar` docs and all other articles, the examples shows that storing a password require only the `ServiceName`:

```
keytar.setPassword('KeytarTest', 'MyAccount', 'password');
```

What prevents other software from requesting and reading this data?

Comment: For anyone who comes here in the future, I found this really helpful: https://github.com/atom/node-keytar/issues/88#issuecomment-365550216

Answer (score 1):

I was able to read keys created by other app in windows. So I have encrypted the value of the key.